# locating where wordpress stores plugin information - for purpose of a git repo

Tags: git, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have installed Revolution Slider plugin for Wordpress and it works just fine.  However, I'm also working in a collaborative environment using GIT, and would like to just push my code to production vs. install the plugin again on the target server.

This of course means that none of the DB information will have been updated.  Revolution Slider installs about 5-6 tables starting with wp_revslider_.. and that's easy to dump and install.

HOWEVER.. there must be some other place in the Wordpress tables where the plugin's state is stored, or /wp-admin wouldn't know it's there.  Which table would this be, and are there any other tables or fields that might have been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin state (active/inactive) is in table wp_options, where "option_name" = "active_plugins".

Sometimes plugin-specific state variables are also stored in wp_options.  Take a look through "/wp-admin/options.php", they are usually prefixed the same way.

---

By the way, one way to figure out where the slider is saving data would be to sqldump a fresh WP database, then install the slider, then sqldump again, now diff the files.

Comment: FEB (for everyone's benefit), the revslider **INSTALL** files are there from the code push, and going to `wp-admin`, the plugin is listed as there, however it's not ACTIVE until you activate it from admin.  I don't think there's a way to push that `wp_options` value over via a project repository.  At least, I had to do it manually.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, `wp_options` isn't even touched at all with the new plugin until you manually activate it; the **only** thing present is the files from the codebase initially.

Comment: Right on that Oliver.  Not sure if you've seen this though: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code